# Convert C function pointer structure into C#

Tags: c#

I need to convert the following code from C to C#. The main problem is the structure. I need to be able to reference the function through a number.
Can anyone help me on this?

```
void test00(void)
{
    printf("This is test 00\r\n");
}

void test01(void)
{
    printf("This is test 01\r\n");
}

void test02(void)
{
    printf("This is test 02\r\n");
}

typedef struct
{
    int test_number;
    int (*func)();
} test_list_type;

test_list_type test_list[] =
{
    {0, test00},
    {1, test01},
    {2, test02}
};

int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        test_list[i].func();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your struct like this:

```
struct test_list_type
{
    int test_number;
    public Action function;
}
```

Then you can make a new instance of the struct like this:

```
var test = new teststruct
{
    test_number = 0,
    function = test02
};
```

And call the method/action like this:

```
test.function();
```